No video output after BIOS upgrade
My PC's WiFi was disconnecting intermittently. I tried common solutions like network reset and reconnecting, but they didn't work. After installing the latest WiFi driver from the MSI website, the issue was resolved. However, I made a mistake by proceeding further.
I then installed all the latest drivers for my motherboard from MSI, including the latest BIOS. The BIOS upgrade was successful, but after restarting, my monitor stopped receiving a signal from the graphics card. I attempted using both HDMI and DP out ports, but the issue persisted.
Interestingly, the same monitor received a signal from my Mac without any problems. I tried troubleshooting by removing and reinserting the RAM and refitting the PCI-E connector on the graphics card, but the problem remained.
The BIOS update took it from V2.C0 to V2.L1. The update was completed successfully from what I remember. Peripherals such as the mouse, keyboard, and fans are receiving power. Additionally, the power LED on the motherboard is on. My PC is just over a year old, and I had never updated any drivers or BIOS before this incident.
Can someone assist me in understanding what might have caused this issue and how to rectify it?
I really appreciate your help on this.
Here are the specs:
Motherboard: MSI B550M PRO VDH WIFI

CPU: AMD RYZEN 7 5700X

RAM: Crucial 3200MHz 16GB DDR4

SSD: Kingston NVME M.2. NV2

Graphics Card: Inno3D RTX 3060 Twin X2 12 GB



Is there any video out when in BIOS setup? 2. If you can see BIOS screen, can you boot from USB, e.g., a Linux live dsitro, such as Ubuntu, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started ? If those work, it's an OS/driver problem. If you can't even see the display in BIOS setup, you likely need professional help fixing the BIOS/firmware issue. See also https://www.reddit.com/r/MSI_Gaming/comments/hkcocc/b550_gaming_pro_no_video_out/


No, right now there is absolutely no video output. I could see the BIOS screen when update was being performed. Usually, on bootup there is a MSI logo at the start, that is not happening now. How do I know I entered BIOS setup when there is no video? Also, some navigation would still be needed to start bootup from flash even in BIOS setup.

As mentioned, " If you can't even see the display in BIOS setup, you likely need professional help fixing the BIOS/firmware issue. See also https://www.reddit.com/r/MSI_Gaming/comments/hkcocc/b550_gaming_pro_no_video_out/"

CMOS reset did the trick here. Bootup happening just fine after the reset. Not sure what caused the issue in the first place though!
